# How would I catch an empty integer in python?

Tags: python, integer, try-catch

I am new to python and I am alright at programming but I am not an expert. I am trying to create a bit of code that will do something based on some user input. There is nothing to specific I want it to do except to be able to do something for every option available.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
C = 0
while C != 1 or 2 or 3:
    C = (input(" "))
    if (int(C)) == 1:            
        function1() 
    elif (int(C)) == 2:         
        function2()
    elif (int(C)) == 3:        
        function3() 
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice ")
```

The problem I have here is that it does what I want, and for every situation I have available, except for when C is left blank. How would I catch this? I have seen many other questions on this topic but all of them are using something called raw_input in there input. I am not using it obviously. Do I just need to simply add something, should I rework my coding, if so how? Thank you very much.

Comment: The conditions you are setting for your `while` are not doing what you think they are doing.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @EdgeAce Please read the duplicate that was just flagged. It is an excellent explanation.

Comment: Can someone remove the absurd duplicate ? The question is about the `input` function not about the goofy while loop ...

Comment: @jadsq Anyway we still lack a bit of information. Does it fail because it was tried after the first input? Is it that it doesn't print `"Invalid Choice"`?

Comment: @idjaw Yes thank you that helps a lot

Comment: @EdgeAce Cheers. Good luck.

Comment: @OliPro007 No multiple inputs work fine with it, I just wanted it to say something if the user were to just hit the enter key and leave the input blank.

Comment: @OliPro007 Tags mentions Try-Catch so some Exception looming around. I would assume that type of trouble  : `>>> a=input(" ")
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
>>> `

Comment: @EdgeAce This question/answer should help you fine tune your code the way you are looking to handle all input types by using exception handling. It has a lot of useful information -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: @EdgeAce If the exception I mentionned above is your problem, then please mention it in the question so that it may be reopened for a proper answer.

Comment: @jadsq That will come up for Python 2. I'm fairly certain that OP is using Python 3 where the error will actually be `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: If the issue is with asking a user for valid input and handling exceptions around that, then it is again a duplicate of the link I posted in my previous comment. At this point it is best if the OP looks at the link I posted and uses that to help solve their problem. There is no point re-opening to close as a dupe again.

Comment: @idjaw You have a very valid point for python2 vs 3. Anyway I feel that in that state, the question won't be valuable to anyone that may reach it; so it essentialy has negative value as it only brings noise to SO ... Anyway that's enough arguing for this, maybe I'll check meta's opinion on this someday .

Comment: @jadsq  fwiw I was never arguing. :) I can't remember the rep requirement but if you are able to vote for reopen, by all means please go ahead. TBH the nature of the question would be a dupe for the answer about handling inputs instead of comparing multiple values.